# Android Studio: How to replace image button with photo after taking a photo in android camera

Tags: android, android-camera

Could anybody help me with a problem that I have?
I would like to make an activity in which i have a make photo button (imageButton_add_playground_image) and after pressing it my app opens up camera for me to take a photo (just one photo).
After making a photo I would like to send it to this activity and change make photo button to a photo made by user (but with leaving make photo button activity on it so the photo could be replaced with different one if this one isn't good enough).
My code in *.java file is as follows:

```
<!-- begin snippet -->

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.RatingBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import static ???.MainActivity.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE;

    public class AddPlayground extends AppCompatActivity {

      EditText playGroundName;
      RatingBar rate;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_playground);
        playGroundName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_playground_name);
        rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        Double message = intent.getDoubleExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      public void addPhoto(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          }
      }

    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

And my code in *.xml file is as follows:

```
<!-- begin snippet -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="???.AddPlayground">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_playground_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Name of playground" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_add_playground_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.52"
            android:onClick="addPhoto"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_playground_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="Playground description" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_playground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addNewPlayground"
            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Under the ??? there is something else but I removed it as it is not crucial to this question.

Answer (score 0):

when you are starting with tutorials you should read whole text... [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) you have full doc (your method `addPhoto` is 1:1 copy of `dispatchTakePictureIntent` method in there)

in short you also need to handle returned bitmap (thumbnail)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        yourImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

receiving full sized `Bitmap` is described in [Save the Full-size Photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) section of above linked doc

Answer (score 0):

The Android Camera application `encodes` the `photo` in the return `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` as a small `Bitmap` in the `extras`, under the key `"data"`.

Use below code to retrieve `image` and displays it in an `ImageButton`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

**Here is the full code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AddPlayground extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText playGroundName;
  RatingBar rate;
  ImageButton imageButton;

  private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_playground);
    playGroundName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_playground_name);
    rate = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_add_playground_image);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Double message = intent.getDoubleExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, 0);

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  public void addPhoto(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageButton.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Make sure you have added below `uses-feature` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` to use the `Camera` feature:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    .......
    ..................
</manifest>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you FAT. It helped a bit, but it replaces the button with very small image (as an icon) and I would like to make it as a photo that fits into the button.